# Can we autowire the java bean in case of Spring MVC form tags?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have seen many examples of Spring MVC form tags and each and every uses code like this:

```
class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // necessary getters and setters (ommited here)
}
```

Now in the `StudentController` they create Student object as:

```
@Controller
class StudentController {
     @RequestMapping("/showForm")
     public String showForm(Model model) {
          model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
          return "show-form";
     }
}
```

My question is that can we make the Student's scope prototype and make it a dependency of StudentController and make it autowired and let Spring inject it in the StudentController, something like this:

```
@Controller
class StudentController {
     @Autowired
     Student student;

     @RequestMapping("/showForm")
     public String showForm(Model model) {
          model.addAttribute("student", student));
          return "show-form";
     }
}
```

Is it a valid point which i am making? If not please explain.

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278595/prototype-bean-doesnt-get-autowired-as-expected

Comment: That doesn't answer my question because i have asked the comaprison of the two cases i have mentioned and i dont want to understand how prototype scope works. I simply want to know whether my suggested way could replace the one used in code examples.

Comment: you are trying to inject a bean of prototype scope into a singleton scope (controller)which cannot happen thats what is being explained there on how to get prototype scope bean .

Comment: Lets forget prototype for a second. Let the scope be singleton, now can we autowire as i have asked. Many people say that it is best practice to do it like model.addAttribute("student", new Student()). I am asking can we do it using autowiring. Does that clear my point @Barath

Comment: yes you can do it provided it is a singleton scope. As you mentioned it is a good practice to do what you have mentioned because Student is a model not a service , creating beans for models  is not many will do.

Comment: I am a beginner. Can you please explain more that why creating beans for models is not a good practice? Also we used Spring to make our code configurable, is the code configurable as model.addAttribute("student", new Student());

Comment: because model have the state specific to the current flow which will be overriden if you inject it somewhere else. As a singletone object it is the same object which will be used across the application. Services are independent of these things, and so they are singltone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sole purpose of the model is to carry data from the view to the corresponding handler in spring.Model is POJO which is plain old object which means it has only getters and setters .suppose in your case what you are trying to do is injecting the dependencies which is autowiring .

1.if the Model is singleton-scoped .the objects are created during the start of the application .i mean why do you want to create an object which has no purpose during the start of the application when its sole purpose is to use as a layer which couples the data.

2.if the Model is prototype scoped

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Student {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

why do want to write to unnecessary code while you can do it with a one liner

```
          model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
```

Hope this helps .

Comment: you can accept my answer that would be a great help .you are welcome

Comment: What if i make the dependency lazy, then the first reason you gave becomes less significant. Now what??

Comment: you are creating unnecessary code all over your project.even if you are putting lazy you are trying to achieve the same thing.imagine in hundreds of places you are doing like this and the time you realize you would have added 1000 more lines to your project.